# What did Cyrus the great look like?

Tags: ancient-iran

Some people think that ancient Iranians (unlike Iranians today) were white and had green/blue eyes and blonde hair.

I am myself an Iranian and I do not look white; I do not have blue/green eyes and do not have blond hair.

I was wondering if there is any evidence how Cyrus the great looked like and if he saw the Iranians of today, would he be surprised that the majority of Iranians do not share his eye/hair/skin color?

Comment: Have you tried searching Google Images for pictures?  Remember that the 2500 years between the time of Cyrus and the present leaves a lot of room for movement & intermarriage between peoples.  As for instance the Islamic conquests, and the subsequent importation of African slaves.  Also, just for what it's worth, all of the dozen or so Iranian immigrants to the US that I've known would certainly be considered "white", even if not blond & blue-eyed.

Comment: @jamesqf: The google images show Cyrus the great same as me but I guess that is not reliable. Yes, we are mixed with Arabs and Mongols and so is any other nation; no single race can claim that they stayed pure. My father is white but I am not; even more interesting, my mom's sister (my aunt) is blonde and has green eyes.

Comment: There are no contemporary portraits of Cyrus. Hence, searching Google Images is pointless.

Comment: There are portraits of Cyrus the great. Unfortunately they do not show colors:-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrus_the_Great#/media/File:Pasargades_winged_man.jpg

Comment: I never noticed "skin color" as we understand it now mentioned in the ancient sources. What color was Hannibal's skin, for example? Perhaps they did not find this relevant.

Comment: Well one thing people should consider is that the Scythians and Alan's were IRANIAN steppe nomads... Scythian have been shown to have red hair and blue eyes... As Herodotus even said also... The Alan's were described by Roman historians as tall people with BLONDE hair. The Persian nobles called themselves Aryan as well as the invaders of India who despite poor coverage and Indian nationalism has been proven... See andovono culture... It's worth noting we were not taught any of this in school... Notice now genetic evidence has suggested white skin first evolved in the middle east and migrated t

Answer (score 14):

For Cyrus specifically, the closest to a contemporary image I could find is this bas-relief found at Pasargadae. I think the best we can really draw from it is that he most likely had a beard. There isn't really any other racially identifying characteristics, and its monochrome so you can't really guess at the hair or skin color that is being portrayed.

[image]

As for the ancient Iranians, our first record of them moving into their ancestral homeland is around [800 BC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Iranians#Second_wave). At that point they likely physically resembled other early Indo-Europeans. The question is what that was.

It is surprisingly difficult to find references to studies of physical appearance outside of sketchy sites pushing racial agendas. What I did dig up tended to agree that skin and hair color appears to have undergone a surprising amount of selection pressure, meaning that these would be among the absolute first features to evolve to match what works best at the latitude a people are living. **So skin color is actually about the *worst* thing to look at to ascertain relations between peoples**.

The best I was able to dig up was [this Science story](https://www.science.org/content/article/how-europeans-evolved-white-skin-rev2). I could be misinterpreting, but it appears to be saying that the PIE people who moved into Europe carried multiple light-skin traits, one of which nearly disappeared in central Europe, but later came back into prominence amongst those that proceeded into northern Europe. The PIE people also appeared to have a tendency to be a bit taller.

Exactly how fast this process evolves I'm not sure. However, Cyrus was only about 2 centuries removed from the Iranian descent into their homeland, so I'd think it fairly likely he was a bit fairer than your typical human being living in the subtropics. But we really don't know.

Comment: Based on that stela I can confidentally state that Cyrus' skin color was "stone" and his eye color was also "stone".

Answer (score 0):

> ancient Iranians (unlike Iranians today) were white and had green/blue
> eyes and blonde hair

— if by that you mean *most* Iranians: *that* is very probably false, as  genetic continuity is more likely than discontinuity between ancient and today peoples (Iranian or not). Based on that continuity though, Cyrus might have been blond, given some Iranians are blond today and at least some were blond then, as illustrated [here](https://qr.ae/pGZB0z):

[image]

That some of the Indo-European invaders — who in many cases ended up constituting the elite of newly created empires and dynasties, like that of the Achemenids — were more fair-skinned/haired that the rest of the population of their empires ***is*** possible.

Is that the case with Cyrus? *We don't know.* (We don't know that kind of physical details on most of ancient personalities.) Although [Pasargadae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasargadae) (the probable "original" location of the Achemenid) is located rather south, that Cyrus was rather blond is not at all an impossibility.